# Drop NA values from scale_fill_* either in aesthetics or in the scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

### Context

I have a dataset that has some `NA` in a variable that is being used for grouping (I know, shocking!). When I throw this data at my `ggplot2` blender, these NA values are treated (by default) as a group/level, which is not what I want for this plot.

I am using a standardized layer configuration for all plots, so I (a) do all data wrangling once, for all plots that will be created and (b) configure all layers that are common to all plots. I save these standard setup in a "blank" `gg` object and then just call it for every plot with the specific variables required for each occasion.

So, if I remove these NA from the overall gg object, I will also loose valid observations for other plots, and unfortunately this would make the client unhappy (and I don't want that). **Surely, I could create a separate data frame just for this plot**, and everything would be nice and dandy, the client would be happy, everyone would be happy. This is exactly how I approached it.

Now that I have time to think, I am curious on what would be the smart `ggplot2` way.

### Reproducible example: the issue

```
gg <- airquality %>%
  # create some NA values in the grouping var
  slice_head(n = 150) %>%
  mutate(group = as.character(sample(c(1:2, NA), 150, replace = TRUE))) %>%
  # standard configs for multiple plots
  ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")
```

One particular plot is giving me trouble

```
gg + geom_density(aes(Solar.R, fill = group), alpha = .7)
```

Which results in:

[image]

### What I have tried

I tried adding `na.translate = FALSE` in the scale layer as described in the docs. It helps, since it removes the NA group from the legend, but density curve is still there:

```
gg <- airquality %>%
  # similar to above, except the scale
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", na.translate = FALSE)
gg + geom_density(aes(Solar.R, fill = group), alpha = .7)
```

[image]

I also tried adding `na.value = NA` to the `scale_fill` function, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Also values like `NULL` and `"blank"` are not permitted by this particular scale.

Finally, I have seen `geom_bar()` examples with `na.rm = TRUE` in the aesthetic definition, but `geom_density()` refuses to accept this solution.

### Question

- How do I drop this `NA` level altogether from one particular plot that is sharing a standard configuration from other sibling plots, without disturbing the others?

I'm guessing there is some clever way of defining the aesthetics, or maybe another argument to `scale_fill_*()` that I'm not aware of.

Comment: No plots were harmed during the making of this question (but some data frames were). And yes, the client was happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one of these approaches would suit?

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

test_data <- airquality %>%
  # create some NA values in the grouping var
  slice_head(n = 150) %>%
  mutate(group = as.character(sample(c(1:2, NA), 150, replace = TRUE)))

# standard configs for multiple plots
gg <- ggplot(test_data) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")

# with NAs
gg + geom_density(aes(Solar.R, fill = group), alpha = .7)
#> Warning: Removed 7 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`).
```

[image]

```r
# without NAs
gg + geom_density(data = test_data %>% filter(!is.na(group)),
                  aes(Solar.R, fill = group), alpha = .7)
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`).
```

[image]

---

Or perhaps this method?

```r
set.seed(123)
gg <- airquality %>%
  # create some NA values in the grouping var
  slice_head(n = 150) %>%
  mutate(group = as.character(sample(c(1:2, NA), 150, replace = TRUE))) %>%
  # standard configs for multiple plots
  {ggplot(data = .) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")}

gg +
    geom_density(data = . %>% filter(!is.na(group)), aes(Solar.R, fill = group), alpha = .7)
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The second method is the winner IMO since it doesn't involve using data that is external to the plot object. Thanks mate!

Comment: You're welcome - glad you solved your problem - thanks for including all the required details in your question\